# Getting Latitude and Longitude Values Using Geocoder

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ios7, google-geocoder

I write the below code for getting Latitude and Longitude Values from an Address.I am having 2 Address fields From and To.

```
-(void)getLatLong:(NSString *)string
{
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:string completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if([placemarks count]) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"coordinate = (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        if([string isEqualToString:self.from.text])
        {
            fromLat = coordinate.latitude;
            fromLng = coordinate.longitude;

        }
        else if([string  isEqualToString:self.to.text])
        {
            toLat = coordinate.latitude;
            toLng = coordinate.longitude;
        }
    }
}];
}  
- (void)display
{
    NSLog(@"%f",fromLat);
    NSLog(@"%f",fromLng);
    NSLog(@"%f",toLat);
    NSLog(@"%f",toLng);
}
- (IBAction)getLatLongs:(id)sender
{
    [self getLatLong:self.from.text];
    [self getLatLong:self.to.text];
    [self display];
}
```

After Clicking the Submit button for First time the output is:

```
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.178 Application[746:70b] 0.000000  
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.179 Application[746:70b] 0.000000  
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.180 Application[746:70b] 0.000000  
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.181 Application[746:70b] 0.000000   
 2014-03-20 10:15:29.019 Application[746:70b] coordinate = (17.387337, 78.480835)  
 2014-03-20 10:15:29.134 Application[746:70b] coordinate = (16.516667, 80.616667)
```

After Clicking the Submit button for Second time the output is:

```
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.178 Application[746:70b] 17.387337  
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.179 Application[746:70b] 78.480835 
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.180 Application[746:70b] 16.516667  
 2014-03-20 10:15:28.181 Application[746:70b] 80.616667  
 2014-03-20 10:15:29.019 Application[746:70b] coordinate = (17.387337, 78.480835)  
 2014-03-20 10:15:29.134 Application[746:70b] coordinate = (16.516667, 80.616667)
```

I want to Know Why it is Getting All Zero's for First time if i call display method after Getting LaltLong Method.

Answer (score 4):

when you call `[self getLatLong:self.from.text];`

It calls `[geocoder geocodeAddressString:string completionHandler:^{}];` which is GCD. Which runs on different thread.

Then you instantly calls `[self display];` till then values are not received in GCD. thats why you are getting **0** first time. 
Next time when you call `[self display];` values are already present so it prints as it is.

Use breakpoints in `-(void)display` and inside GCD to get more idea.

try to call `[self display];` inside GCD.

```
-(void)getLatLong:(NSString *)string
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:string completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if([placemarks count]) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"coordinate = (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        if([string isEqualToString:self.from.text])
        {
            fromLat = coordinate.latitude;
            fromLng = coordinate.longitude;
            [self display];
        }
        else if([string  isEqualToString:self.to.text])
        {
            toLat = coordinate.latitude;
            toLng = coordinate.longitude;
            [self display];
        }
    }
    }];
} 

- (void)display
{
   NSLog(@"%f",fromLat);
   NSLog(@"%f",fromLng);
   NSLog(@"%f",toLat);
   NSLog(@"%f",toLng);
}

- (IBAction)getLatLongs:(id)sender
{
   [self getLatLong:self.from.text];
   [self getLatLong:self.to.text];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I Solved My Problem Using "Dispatch_Time"

Answer (score 0):

i Solved My Problem Like This It's Working Fine

```
-(void)getLatLong:(NSString *)string
{
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:string completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
if([placemarks count]) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"coordinate = (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
    if([string isEqualToString:self.from.text])
    {
        fromLat = coordinate.latitude;
        fromLng = coordinate.longitude;

    }
    else if([string  isEqualToString:self.to.text])
    {
        toLat = coordinate.latitude;
        toLng = coordinate.longitude;
    }
}
}];
}  
- (void)display
{
 NSLog(@"%f",fromLat);
 NSLog(@"%f",fromLng);
 NSLog(@"%f",toLat);
 NSLog(@"%f",toLng);
}
- (IBAction)getLatLongs:(id)sender
{
 [self getLatLong:self.from.text];
 [self getLatLong:self.to.text];
  int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

       [self display];
    });
}

}
```

Comment: This might create same problem in some scenarios.
What if you are not able to get values within 1.5 sec? or if you get values with 0.5 sec you are wasting your 1 sec ;)

Comment: @RahulV.Mane the Main Purpose is I Want to Get Those Lat and Long Values and Use them Later. Can u please give me another suggestion.

Comment: If this is the case then you dont have worry about printing the values. You can write `NSLog` in GCD where you receive values. as i can see `fromLat, fromLng, toLat, toLng` are global variables. so if the concern is "when to print values?" then it should be printed when it receives. ie. inside `if/else` block :)

Comment: @RahulV.Mane No it's Not Working if i Write NSLog at the time of Usage First it Shows All Zeros For Second Time it Shows the lat long values.